# Make the image inside a div appear behind its div background

Tags: css, html, z-index

I have a div that has background that is partly transparent with a watermark. Inside of the div I'm calling an image but I want that image to appear behind the background of the div so I can have the watermarked transparent div background appear over the image. Is that possible? Here's the css that I have that isn't working...

```
.artist-container {
background:url(images/artist-back.png);
    width:310px;
    height:376px;
    margin-left:-9px;
    z-index:331;
    position:relative;
}
.artist-container img {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin-left:5px;
    z-index:330;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: So you want a background for your background, so you can background while you're backgrounding? Yo dawg...

Comment: You can as well apply watermark on the fly with PHP:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426207/php-how-to-add-text-watermark-on-an-image][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426207/php-how-to-add-text-watermark-on-an-image

Comment: You really shouldn't do it this way. An image isn't *truly* watermarked unless the watermark is *a part of the image*. If it's not combined, anyone could still easily just save the image behind the watermark and have the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By giving `.artist-container` a higher z-index, you are placing it higher in the stacking order than the child image, though children always have a higher z-index than their parents.

If you want to give the effect of a watermark, you can:

1. Make the image the background of the div and place an image watermark inside it.
2. Position another div within `.artist-container` absolutely, with the same dimensions as that of the image and with a higher z-index of the image, with the watermark as the background.

Comment: This removes the semantic meaning of the image, as it will always be a watermark image (background images don't show up when printing, for example).

Answer (score 3):

I whipped up a small sample using some spans, which won't add any semantic content to your document and will still maintain the semantic meaning of your image.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="cover_contain">
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/hla4q.jpg" alt="[image]" width="128" height="128" />
   <span class="cover_image"></span>
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
span.cover_contain {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
span.cover_image {
    display: block;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/5BtFV.png') center center no-repeat;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Live Preview**](http://jsfiddle.net/76yHV/3/)

Answer (score 0):

make the image as the background-image of the div and the watermark as the img

Comment: This removes the semantic meaning of the image, as it will always be a watermark image (background images don't show up when printing, for example).

Comment: yea... but you can't have the background image of a div in front of anything that's inside of it.  You'd almost need another div in front of that div and have the background image of that to be the watermark

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to put a background in front of an image of the image is in that element. You can simply use the main image as background, or:

what you could do

```
<div class="holder">
    <img src=".." class="main_image">
    <img src=".." class="watermark">
</div>

.holder {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
 }

 .main_image {
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     z-index:0;
 }
.watermark {
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     z-index:9;
 }
```

Comment: The background isn't so much a watermark as it is a transparent background with effects I want over the image. The image is called with php and changes so I can't set the original div to the image background. My only guess is to place the div under the image and then give it a negative top margin to overlap it. Is that the only option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the negative `z-index`, but in that case you must have the wrapper not to have *any* `z-index`. It's one of the features of stacking context.

Here is a demo fiddle: http://dabblet.com/gist/1731538

And the code for you would be something like this:

```
.artist-container {
    background:url(images/artist-back.png);
    width:310px;
    height:376px;
    margin-left:-9px;
    position:relative;
}
.artist-container img {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin-left:5px;
    z-index:-1;
    position:relative;
}
```